# How to get server name and database from config file

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a connection string in my config file and i am using it in my code as follows -

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCentralW2"].ConnectionString);
```

I need to get the server name and the database from this and pass it as a parameter to my stored proc.

I am trying to get it as below but it is failing.

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCentralW2"].ConnectionString);
SqlConnectionStringBuilder conbuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conbuilder.ConnectionString = sqlconn.ToString();
string server = conbuilder.DataSource;
string database = conbuilder.InitialCatalog;
```

Please help me get the database and server name from my config file

Comment: How is it failing?  What happens?

Comment: Why are you creating a `SqlConnection` and not using it except to get back the same connection string you passed it?

Answer (score 2):

Your not assigning the connection string property correctly, try:

```
builder.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCentralW2"].ConnectionString;
```

Or initialize your `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class with the connection string e.g.

```
var conBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCentralW2"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();    
        builder.ConnectionString = sqlconn.ConnectionString;
        string server = builder.DataSource;
        string database = builder.InitialCatalog;
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend that you store your connection string in your web.config than take it as it is, rather than build it

in web.config

```
<add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=dbtest; Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

in the cs file

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        con.Open();
```

Comment: I got it...

It should have been 

  string database = sqlconn.DataSource;
                             string server = sqlconn.DataSource;